# Attach 2 tables in iText 7

Tags: java, spring, itext, itext7

how can I attach 2 iText Tables to each other? Please see the attached image (I need to attach table A and table B).

I tried to create Table C with colspan = 1 and add A and B as cells, but it didn't help.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Remove the margins?

Comment: Yes, like it's a one table.

Comment: Maybe `setSpacingBefore(0)` and `setSpacingAfter(0)`

Comment: `setMarginBottom()` and `setMarginTop()` solved the problem. 

ps.  `setMarginBottom()` and `setMarginTop()`  replaced  `setSpacingBefore()`  and  `setSpacingAfter()` in iText 7.

Answer (score 0):

`setMarginBottom() and setMarginTop()` solved the problem.

PS. `setMarginBottom() and setMarginTop()` replaced `setSpacingBefore() and setSpacingAfter(`) in `iText 7`